# Importing COLLADA file - Wrong vertex positions

Tags: import, polygon, collada

I'm working on a .DAE import for my game engine. I've been working with models exported by MilkShape, and they work fine:

- My engine: http://snag.gy/yj7tl.jpg
- SketchUp: http://snag.gy/6120D.jpg

Now i've downloaded a bigger poly mesh (with skeleton) form the internet, and im trying to import that one. I would only like the mesh and won't need the skeleton / animations for now.

Problem is, the output in my engine is not correct.

- My Engine: http://snag.gy/RkfR3.jpg
- Sketchup: http://snag.gy/4Plxq.jpg

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Do these results ring a bell for someone?

Here's the .DAE files by the way;

- 4models (milkshape exported): http://pastebin.com/wRgqTLZN
- juliet (unknown export (7MB!)): http://files.dukesoft.nl/juliet.dae

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it figured out!

The one model (the Milkshape one) used the

section like so;

0 0 0 1 1 1 2 3 2

Where:

```
0=<position index> 0=<normal_index> 0=<vertex index>
1=<position index> 1=<normal_index> 1=<vertex index>
2=<position index> 3=<normal_index> 2=<vertex index>
```

But the other model didn't use this offset and used shared index over both position, normal and vertex.

0 1 2 3

Where:

```
0 = <position index & normal_index & vertex index>
1 = <position index & normal_index & vertex index>
2 = <position index & normal_index & vertex index>'
3 = <position index & normal_index & vertex index>
```

You can see the 4models has:

```
<triangles material="Block" count="12">
    <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Box01-geometry-vertices" offset="0" />
    <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Box01-normals" offset="1" />
    <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#Box01-texcoords" offset="2" />
    <p>0 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 1 3 0 (...)</p> (vertexes X 3 numbers)
</triangles>
```

The other one has:

```
<triangles material="Block" count="12">
    <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Box01-geometry-vertices" />
    <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Box01-normals" />
    <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#Box01-texcoords" />
    <p>0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8 9 10 11 (...)</p> (vertexes X 1 numbers)
</triangles>
```

So, all i had to do is remove the hardcoded offsets and use the offets from the XML.